# Añadir cadena de texto CASE

Tags: sql

Estoy empezando en SQL y me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que el resultado para CASE (nombre corregido) también contenga el apellido de cada persona (Black y Rubio).

```
SLECT
    name,
    CASE
        WHERE name LIKE "Alesia%" THEN "Alexia"
        WHERE name LIKE "Abel%" THEN "Alexia"
        ELSE name
        END AS nombre_corregido
    FROM `proyecto-2-417210.customer_data.customer_address`
```

Resultados:

```
name: 
1   Chad Lucero
2   Elouan Blanchard
3   Nomusa Knight
4   Abel Black
5   Alesia Rubio

nombre_corregido
1   Chad Lucero
2   Elouan Blanchard
3   Noumusa Knight
4   Alexia
5   Alexia
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra tanto la consulta como los datos de ejemplo _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes dividir name en dos partes en "first_name" y "last_name" haciendo una subconsulta en el FROM y luego aplicar el tu lógica a first_name únicamente:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    CASE
        WHEN first_name LIKE 'Alesia%' THEN 'Alexia'
        WHEN first_name LIKE 'Abel%' THEN 'Alexia'
        ELSE first_name
    END AS first_name_corregido,
    last_name AS apellido
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1) AS first_name,
        SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE(' ', name) + 1) AS last_name
    FROM `proyecto-2-417210.customer_data.customer_address`
) AS split_names
```

Comment: Gracias Stefan!

Comment: Stefan, espera que la gente edite y mejores las preguntas, no promuevas el desorden.

Comment: @OCHOA Perdona que desorden, lo que he hecho ha sido arreglar la pregunta. Lo podría haberlo hecho desde la pestaña del "Resvisión" pero es lo mismo...

Comment: @MissOuton De nada, pon la respuesta con el tick también para poder cerrarla.

Comment: Se le pidió al OP (en dos comentarios) que pusiera en texto lo que tiene, apresurarse a responder no es lo mejor cuando no se ve en el OP un interés por seguir las pautas del sitio. Si tienes una respuesta lo mejor es decirle al OP que en cuanto edite la pregunta y siga los lineamientos del sitio le ayudaras y listo...

Comment: @Stefan _cerrar_ una pregunta no es lo mismo que _aceptar una respuesta_. Una respuesta aceptada implica que le ha sido lo más útil a OP, no necesariamente que "el caso se haya solucionado". Las preguntas se cierran por diversos motivos (estar basadas en opiniones, necesitar detalles o aclaraciones, solicitar recursos externos...) Recordá siempre contestar preguntas _bien formadas_. Leé [answer].